# Multiple users with one autologin

Tags: raspberry-pi, autologin, multi-user

I use raspberry pi os with desktop similar to debian

Is it possible to have two different users, and one of them perform auto login.?

Something like when I power on my raspberry, if I do nothing, it use user one and auto login.

But if I power on my raspberry and during starting I press the shift key, the pop-up windows for entering user/password appairs and I could login with user2

Thanks.